# Transform XML with tree data structure to flat structure using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform XML with tree structure into a flat list. This is a small part of input XML that I am trying to transform:

```
<category_list>
    <category>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>Forks</name>
        <sub_categories>
            <category>
                <id>15</id>
                <name>26"</name>
                <sub_categories />
            </category>
            <category>
                <id>16</id>
                <name>27,5"</name>
                <sub_categories />
            </category>
            <category>
                <id>19</id>
                <name>27,5+"</name>
                <sub_categories />
            </category>
            <category>
                <id>17</id>
                <name>29"</name>
                <sub_categories />
            </category>
        </sub_categories>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>13</id>
        <name>Shocks</name>
        <sub_categories />
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>14</id>
        <name>Springs</name>
        <sub_categories />
    </category>
</category_list>
```

I need output like this:

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>Forks</name>
        <parent_category>0</parent_category>
        <order_by>1</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>15</id>
        <name>26"</name>
        <parent_category>12</parent_category>
        <order_by>1</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>16</id>
        <name>27,5"</name>
        <parent_category>12</parent_category>
        <order_by>2</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>19</id>
        <name>27,5+"</name>
        <parent_category>12</parent_category>
        <order_by>3</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>17</id>
        <name>29"</name>
        <parent_category>12</parent_category>
        <order_by>4</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>13</id>
        <name>Shocks</name>
        <parent_category>0</parent_category>
        <order_by>2</order_by>
    </category>
    <category>
        <id>14</id>
        <name>Springs</name>
        <parent_category>0</parent_category>
        <order_by>3</order_by>
    </category>
</categories>
```

I have no idea how to do it. First problem is to change tree structure to flat list and second problem is add an order_by tag that increments with category count.

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process all `//category` and then use `position()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="category_list">
        <categories>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//category"/>
        </categories>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::sub_categories)]"/>
            <parent_category>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../parent::category">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../parent::category/id"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </parent_category>
            <order_by>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </order_by>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is working but there is one problem. Parent category is always ID of the first category in the list. If category Shocks is before Forks then all subcategories of Forks has parent_category=13 instead of 12.

Comment: So it looks like I figure it out. I used in condition ancestor::category instead of ../../category and ancestor::category/id in value-of. Looks like it works now how I need. Thx a lot for help Martin.

Comment: @sajushko, sorry about the problem, I had the wrong XPath there, now fixed, although you also found a fix on your own.